# Etymology of 'Muggles'

Tags: harry-potter, etymology

The title says it all really: **what is the etymology of JK Rowling's word 'Muggle'?**

I have read from the [Harry Potter Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Muggle) that:

> Muggle is derived from the word "mug," which refers to a gullible
>   person. J. K. Rowling has commented that she added a syllable to
>   soften the word, which she wanted to suggest "both foolishness and
>   lovability." In the Brazilian translation of the series the term
>   "muggle" was adapted to "trouxa", which literally means "fool", albeit
>   not necessarily lovable at all.

However there is no citation to confirm the reliability of this.  I am looking for **a quote from JK Rowling which confirms (or refutes) this.**

Comment: this is what you'd call `source-request`. Also a showcase of why wikia should usually be avoided as a 'source' for answers in this site.

Comment: @naxa aren't most questions source requests in some form or another?  And as for Wikias some can be exceptionally high quality. Besides I'm not using it as a source for an answer; because of the lack of references in the HP wikis I am posing this question.  Perhaps you didn't see that I specifically asked for a quote that confirms **or refutes** the above claim!

Comment: sorry I wasn't very clear. I understand perfectly what you are doing here, I am happy with you doing that, can confirm about existence of good quality wikias, and generally agree with you. Despite my unfortunate arrogance, I've mentioned the `source-request` thing because I like its wording and wished to see it here, but found no other apropos to add it. On off word though, in wikias however good quality, I find no rational value until it meets the referencing standards of Wikipedia, which usually would be sufficient nowadays in my opinion, but I saw rather few wikias taking merit in doing so.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Rowling commented on this in a [2004 live chat on World Book Day](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0304-wbd.htm)

> **julesrbf**: Where did you come up with the word "muggle"?
>
> **Rowling:** I was looking for a word that suggested both foolishness and loveability. The word 'mug' came to mind, for somebody gullible, and then I softened it. I think 'muggle' sounds quite cuddly. I didn't know that the word 'muggle' had been used as drug slang at that point... ah well.

Comment: Perftect answer: +1 :D

Comment: @N_Soong Always happy to help. Now to go and add a citation on the HP Wiki, and make the world a less awful place

Comment: I didn't know the word 'muggle' had been used as drug slang until this particular point myself.

Comment: Muggle sounds cuddly because of snuggle.

Comment: @Benjol Indirectly, yes. More directly, it sounds cuddly and ‘softened’ because it’s a transparently recognisable diminutive.

Comment: It sounds druggy because of Smuggle

Comment: @Hurkyl Actually it currently refers to marijuana. But decades ago it referred to tobacco (if I am remembering right)! In the early part of last century for example. OED doesn't cite this; it cites Rowling as coining the term. Furthermore it's been taken on a meaning in the IT community (including security) e.g. it's in the Jargon file, for example (OED also notes a IT reference and more generally any field).

Comment: [There's a _Time_ article from **1931** using "muggles"](https://content.time.com/time/subscriber/article/0,33009,742157,00.html) among other words to refer to marijuana cigarettes.